# I am having trouble with scipy's solve_bvp

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I have been trying to translate this section of an ODE over to python for weeks, but I constantly run into different errors when running it. I thought my understanding of `solve_bvp` was general, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have been reading the libraries' documentation for how the individual functions work and I don't feel like I am genuinely understanding it after many weeks.

Problem:

[image]

That is the math I am trying to recreate and below is the code I came up with.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy

#Constants#
P1 = 0.05
P2 = 0.1
Tau = 0.5
W = 1
Uh = 1
Uv = 1.562
Bv1 = 1.59
Bv2 = 1.59
A1 = 1.2
A2 = 0.8
Roe1 = 0.177
Roe2 = 0.177
Nh = 9.3
Nv = 128
Qh = 10
Qv = 100
H = 1

#g is lamda this variable will change with time#
#This is variable test area#

g = 1

BH1 = 1
BH2 = 2

x1 = np.array([0, 1])
x2 = (0, 1)
t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=365)
#############################################

i = input('What is the value of i?')
i = ([int(i)])
#Functions#


def Bhinv(i):
    if i == 1:
        l = BH1*min(Nv/(Qv*int(Nh)), 1)+int(Roe1)*H*min(Nv/(Qh*int(Nh)), 1)
        return l
    if i == 2:
        l = BH2*min(Nv/(Qv*Nh), 1)+Roe2*H*min(Nv/(Qh*Nh), 1)
        return l
    else:
        return print("Null")


def sys1(x1, x2, i):
    if i.all() == 1:
        dx1dt = ((int(P1)/g)-1)*Uh*x1[0] + \
            (((int(Bhinv(1)))/g)*(int(Nh)/Nv)*x2[0])
        dx2dt = ((int(Bv1)/g)*(Nv/Nh)*x1[0])-int(Uv)*x2[0]
        return dx1dt, dx2dt

    if i.all() == 2:
        dx1dt = ((P2/g)-1)*Uh*x1(t)+(((BH2)/g)*(Nh/Nv)*x2(t))
        dx2dt = ((Bv2/g)*(Nv/Nh)*x1(t))-Uv*x2(t)
        return dx1dt, dx1dt

# BRN(Bhi) (i = 1,2)


def step1(x1, x2):
    x1 = 1
    x2 = 0
    return np.array([1, 0, 0])


y = ([0, 0],
     [0, 0])
v1s1 = scipy.integrate.solve_bvp(sys1, step1, x1, y, x2, y)
```

The current error I am dealing with is `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

Comment: (1) Please share the ODE you're trying to solve, including the boundary conditions. (2) I'm guessing that the `i` variable is used to select between the two cases in the photo you shared. For the sake of simplicity, remove the user input and adjust the code to only work for one case. It's best to simplify the problem like that so you can focus on getting it working before you add more complexity.

Comment: (3) Your `step1` function is supposed to be your boundary conditions function. As is, it does not make use of `x1` or `x2`, so the solver will not know how to adjust things to satisfy the condition. (4) You're passing more arguments than you should to `solve_bvp`. The third and fourth arguments are `x` and `y`, but after that is `p` and `S`, which I'm not sure you intend to use.

Comment: (5) I commented this on your original (and since deleted post): for a minimal reproducible example, you should remove unnecessary imports. `import math` and `from scipy import integrate` are not used. You also don't use the `decimal` library, yet you import it and called `getcontext`, which do nothing in your example.

Comment: @jared Okay, based on your feedback how should I rewrite this code for it to work? Based on what you have said I gather you have a full understanding of how this function operates so seeing it in action may be the best way for me to correct my mistake as opposed to explaining how the function works.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the function, but I can't show you how to solve your problem because you haven't shared enough information about your problem. I still don't know what the ODE is or what the boundary conditions are. I can try and help you after you've made the edits I suggested.

Comment: That should be added to your question rather than put as a comment.

Comment: Full error massage please!

Comment: @jared I have updated the original post with the full photo

Comment: Blaise, this is an interesting problem, but it's pretty complex if you're new to coding in general and scipy in particular. My advice is to back up and try something simpler to build up to it. E.g. solve a simple IVP, then solve an IVP with the ODE you have shown, and try different values of any free parameters and see how the solution changes. If you get that far, then go back to the BVP and work on that again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a boundary value problem, you have an initial value problem. These can be solved using [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). Since this is a large problem (you need to solve it for `i=1` and `i=2` and optimize the values `beta_h1`, `beta_h2`, and `lambda` to achieve some conditions), I used the value 1 for all those unknowns and only implemented a solver for the `i=1` case.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

p1 = 0.05
p2 = 0.1
tau = 0.5
omega = 1
mu_h = 1
mu_v = 1.562
beta_v1 = 1.59
beta_v2 = 1.59
a1 = 1.2
a2 = 0.8
rho1 = 0.177
rho2 = 0.177
Nh = 9.3
Nv = 128
Qh = 10
Qv = 100
H = 1

beta_h1 = 1
beta_h2 = 2

lamb = 1


def beta_h1_func(beta_h):
    return beta_h*min(Nv/Qv/Nh, 1) + rho1*H*min(Nv/Qh/Nh, 1)


def beta_v1_func(t):
    p = a1 if t < tau else (omega - a1*tau)/(omega-tau)
    return beta_v1*min(Qv*Nh/Nv, 1)*p


def ode1(t, x):
    x1, x2 = x
    dx1dt = (rho1/lamb - 1)*mu_h*x1 + (beta_h1_func(beta_h1)*Nh/lamb/Nv)*x2
    dx2dt = (beta_v1_func(t)*Nv/lamb/Nh)*x1 - mu_v*x2
    return [dx1dt, dx2dt]


x01 = np.array([1, 0])
x02 = np.array([0, 1])
t = np.linspace(0, omega, 100)
sol1 = solve_ivp(ode1, [t.min(), t.max()], x01, t_eval=t)
v1 = sol1.y[:, -2:-1]
sol2 = solve_ivp(ode1, [t.min(), t.max()], x02, t_eval=t)
v2 = sol2.y[:, -2:-1]

rho = np.max(np.linalg.eigvals(np.hstack((v1, v2))))
print(rho)  # 0.6812599731032912
```

Now, this code is not perfect. You have a large number of variables that would normally be passed to the functions, but I took the lazy route and left them in the global scope. This isn't good practice, but it's what I did for simplicity.

Comment: It is a BVP, but with homogeneous linear ODE. Thus the transfer matrix from the left to the right side can be computed from two IVP solutions. The aim is to find parameters so that a "periodic" solution exists where the left boundary state is equal to the right boundary state, and overall the transfer matrix is non-expanding. The periodicity is easily implemented in the BC function, the non-expanding nature not so much. If that is done in a sensible way, it is likely a non-smooth condition, that solve_bvp will have problems with, same as with the jump in the coefficient function.

Comment: @LutzLehmann While the overall problem may be a BVP, the solution process described is to solve it as an IVP and find the variables that satisfy the condition. Hence why I said it's an IVP.

Comment: But the question, apart from the misunderstandings of the interface and the coding errors, was about transforming an existing BVP solution process via single-shooting method (which indeed uses IVP solutions) into a solution process employing a more general BVP solver. // One could be of the opinion that such a question belongs better on scicomp.SE

Comment: @LutzLehmann Do you suggest someone should post a solution to this problem using the BVP solver or stick to an IVP solver since the document shared by OP outlines the shooting method?

Comment: That would violate "not a coding service". The formulation of the problem as it is is designed for the single-shooting approach. One would have to reverse-engineer the algorithm to extract the minimal mathematical content to get a suitable BVP. As said, the place for that is scicomp.SE or math.SE. The only answer here should be RTFM (friendly, of course) about the proper use of the function interfaces `sys(t,x,p)` and `bc(xa,xb,p)`.